# Sharepoint 2013 тестирование чтения и записи offline

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Написание методов доступа чтения и записи в list sharepoint без использования его самого. Может быть есть эмуляция или api для эмуляции?

Comment: Эмуляция шарепоинта? Я сомневаюсь.

Comment: Думаю микрософт предумотрели, что дома не у всех развернут sharepoint

Comment: Помнится, когда я под него писал, лет 5 назад, я разворачивал самую простую версию шарепоинта локально. Может сейчас то изменилось, хз

Comment: А ей AD не нужен?

Comment: Этого, к сжалению, точно не помню. Вроде не нужен.